# adding additional zero to a post

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, integer

Let's take this line for instance

```
  $amount = $_POST["priceFinal"];
```

which is essentially equivilant to

```
  $amount = 5000;
```

I would like to add two zero at the end so if the amount if 5000 its actually 5000000

Now its important to note that it must remain has an integer, where if i do

```
  $amount = "".$_POST["priceFinal"]."00";
```

it does the work but its a string and needs to remain an integer

Comment: $amount = $amount * 100;

Comment: Above or use intval() or integer type casting.

Comment: why multiply it by 100 out of curiosity

Comment: Your example above is actually three zeroes, but I assume you would want 500000 in which you multiple 5000 by 100 to get 500000, basic mathematics.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh 1. `int()` ?! 2. Why the first concatenation?! completely useless! 3. `;)` What?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh int() isn't a function, it is `intval($str)` or `(int) $str` (the latter is type casting)

Comment: sorry my mistake. please try $amount = intval($_POST["priceFinal"].'00');but try to just use multiplication.

Comment: Since when `$_POST` contains anything but strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just times you amount by how many 0's you need. for example times by 10 gives you 1 extra 0. so just times by 100 to get two extra 0, this keeps it as an interger as opposed to converting it to a sting as php will always try to assume a variable type.

```
 $amount = $_POST["priceFinal"] * 100;
```

see this link for more information on definition type. [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this assuming you are not calculating anything with it.

```
// see php.net str_pad for more examples.
$amount = str_pad($_POST['priceFinal'], 2 , '0');
```